# Xcode Storyboard not finding any custom classes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

Im using custom segues and viewcontrollers in my project. Until not hooking the storyboard viewcontrollers and segues with my custom ones worked as usual. Yesterday i had to force quit xcode. Today when i try to change the class of a viewController in the storyboard view to my custom class xcode does not give me the autocomplete option, so i just fill it out manually. When i simulate the app and go the the new viewcontroller i get the error:
"this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key: button"
button is the only referenced outlet in this view (i checked it in connector inspector). all the other propsed solutions on stackoverflow to this problem did not solve it for me. it looks to me like the storyboard file is broken or something if even a single referencing outlet does not work and storyboard does not find any of my custom classes? does anyone have an idea whats happening here?

Comment: Close the xcode and then start again. This helps sometimes.